# $\int_X f^p d\mu = p\int_{[0,+\infty)} t^{p-1}\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>t\}) d\mu_t$ for any natural $p\ge 1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:X\mapsto[0,+\infty)$ be a non-negative measurable function defined on the space $X$, endowed with the complete $\sigma$-additive, $\sigma$-finite, measure $\mu$ defined on the $\sigma$-algebra of the measurable subsets of $X$.

I read that, for $p\in\mathbb{N}$, $p\ge 1$, $$\int_X f^p d\mu = p\int_{[0,+\infty)} t^{p-1}\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>t\}) d\mu_t$$

I know that the equality holds for $p=1$, as proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851049/an-equality-concerning-the-lebesgue-integral). That also implies that $$\int_X f^p d\mu =\int_{[0,+\infty)} \mu(\{x\in X: f(x)^p>t\}) d\mu_t,$$but I am not able to use this result, nor induction, to prove the desired result. How could we prove it? I heartily thank any answerer!

*EDIT*: This question has been marked as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338275/proof-of-int-0-inftyptp-1-mu-xfx-geq-t-d-mut-int-0-inft), but, although related, they do not ask the same question.

Comment: Why not use Fubini as before?

Comment: $\int_0^\infty pt^{p-1}\mu\{f>t\}dt=\int_0^{\infty}\int_Xpt^{p-1}\mathbf 1_{\{f>t\}} d\mu dt=\int_X\int_0^{\infty}pt^{p-1}\mathbf 1_{\{f>t\}}dtd\mu=\int_X\int_0^fpt^{p-1}dtd\mu=\int_X f^pd\mu$

Comment: @user1161 By taking the explanations [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851049/an-equality-concerning-the-lebesgue-integral#comment3789087_1851313) into account, I'm able to understand this. Thank you so much!

Comment: "This question has been marked as a duplicate of this, but, although related, they do not ask the same question." Sorry but did you even read the answers over there? Please explain how these do not address the question here.

Comment: Why is the function $h(t,\mu) = pt^{p-1} \chi_{\{f>t\}}$ measurable?

Comment: Don't we have to show that this function is integrable or at least measurable to use Fubini?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply change of variables to the expression you have. You deduced that:
$$\int_X f^p d\mu =\int_{[0,+\infty)} \mu(\{x\in X: f(x)^p>t\}) d\mu_t,$$
where $\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)^p>t\}=\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>t^{1/p}\}$. Now substitute $t\mapsto t^p$ and the result follows because the derivative of this map is $pt^{p-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure about how to change variables, since I've only learnt that $\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)dx=\int_a^b f(g(t))g'(t) dt$ for $f,g'\in C[a,b]$...

Comment: This is actually the result I have applied with $f(t)=\mu(\{x\in X: f(x)>t^{1/p}\}$ and $g(t)=t^p$. It turns out that the change of variables formula is also valid for the Lebesgue integral (see https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~grigor/mwlect.pdf section 3 for instance).

Comment: Thank you again! Forgive me: the result you refer to is at p. 86, am I right? The hypothesis are that $f\in L^1[a,b]$ and $\varphi\in C^1[\alpha,\beta]$, $\varphi^{-1}\in C^1[a,b]$, correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have asked a [separate question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1859160/lebesgue-integration-by-substitution) addressed to the issue.